# FORMAT([Time], 'hh:mm') returns NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, time, format

I have a Calendar table [with the following structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSUm2.png):

```
CalendarID    nvarchar(13)
Date          date
Time          time(7)
```

with data such as:

[image: Calendar table data]

Formatting the time column as `hhmm` works:

```
SELECT [CalendarID]
     , FORMAT([Date], 'ddd, MMM dd, yyyy') AS [DATE]
     , FORMAT([Time], 'hhmm') AS [Time]
FROM [dbo].[Calendar]
```

[image: select time format (hhmm)]

But formatting as `hh:mm` does not work and displays `NULL`:

```
SELECT [CalendarID]
     , FORMAT([Date], 'ddd, MMM dd, yyyy') AS [DATE]
     , FORMAT([Time], 'hh:mm') AS [Time]
FROM [dbo].[Calendar]
```

[image: select time format (hh:mm)]

How can I format it as `hh:mm`?

Comment: The docs explains the format string you should be using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017. Its always worth checking the reference docs before asking on SO.

Comment: @DaleBurrell, I understood by your link, thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> FORMAT relies upon CLR formatting rules, which dictate that colons and
>   periods must be escaped. Therefore, when the format string (second
>   parameter) contains a colon or period, the colon or period must be
>   escaped with backslash when an input value (first parameter) is of the
>   time data type.

This should work:

```
SELECT FORMAT(CAST('09:00:00.1234567' AS TIME(7)), 'hh\:mm')              -- 09:00
SELECT FORMAT(CAST('09:00:00.1234567' AS TIME(7)), 'hh\:mm\:ss\.fffffff') -- 09:00:00.1234567
```

Answer (score 3):

Try it in this way:

```
FORMAT([Time], N'hhmm') AS [Time]
```

or

```
FORMAT([Time], N'hh\:mm') AS [Time]
```

Comment: Than your for your suggestion. However, it's still not work for me. I'm using Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8 Nov 20 2018 21:01:54 Copyright (C) 2018 Microsoft Corporation.

Comment: second option worked for me. SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be very picky about input types.  This will return NULL:

```
declare @theNow as time
set @theNow = cast(getdate() as time)
print format(@theNow, N'hh\:mm tt')
```

whereas this will print your expected result string:

```
declare @theNow as datetime
set @theNow = cast(getdate() as datetime)
print format(@theNow, N'hh\:mm tt')
```

I'm still trying to work out the details myself.

Comment: I found the same thing as you. If the input is the "Time" datatype, Format() returns NULL. If the input is cast to datetime or datetime2, then it works as expected. Checked in MSSQL 2017 and 2019.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check the docs about date and datetime

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

After Larnu's warning

**Update:**

From the above link you can format the time like that;

```
SELECT FORMAT(cast(GETDATE() as time), N'hh\:mm\:ss');
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Link only answers will often attract downvotes as they the links can become dead and then aren't useful to others. If you are linking to another site as the answer it's important to include the relevant parts from the webpage to answer the OP's question(s). Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Lamu, Actually I tried to send the post as a comment but stack overflow said that "you can not comment under the 50 reputation" and send it as an answer. Sorry for that, I'll improve my answer.

Comment: Correct, you need 20 reputation points to post a comment on a question. It doesn't take long to get those, and improving your answer here is one step to getting them. :)