# How to get time in AM/PM 08:00AM format in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is the query I am using:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(varchar(15), CAST('08:00:00.0000000' AS TIME), 100)
```

And I get this output:  `8:00AM`

I want the output to be this: `08:00AM`   (two digit hours)

How can I get this output?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

SQL Server way of LPAD

```
SELECT RIGHT('0'+ CONVERT(varchar(15),CAST('08:00:00.0000000' AS TIME),100), 7)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT FORMAT(start_time,'hh:mm tt') AS start_time
FROM table_name
```

Comment: I get NULL result

Comment: @henryloke https://stackoverflow.com/a/54213358/11683. After fixing to `hh\:mm\ tt` it will still give a null because a `time` is [formatted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks) according to the [rules of `Timespan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings), and Timespan cannot have am/pm. If the time in question is indeed a point in time (as opposed to a duration), it should be a `datetime` or similar.